# The Betti numbers of of $CP^n\sharp CP^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

I have known that $b_2(CP^n\sharp CP^n)=2$, however I have no idear how to prove this fact ! I appreciate any help for this simple question! Thank you!

Comment: When you say you know this, where did you see this claimed? And how much algebraic topology have you studied?

Comment: I have know this fact from the paper I am reading. In fact I have studied little about the algebraic topology. I am very thankful, if you offer me the reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those calculations which is easier with the general formalism of homology, rather than just Betti numbers. Using the [Mayer-Vietoris theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence) a few times, one can show that if $M$ and $N$ are connected $n$-manifolds and $k\ne n-1,n$, then

$$H_k(M\mathbin{\#}N)\cong H_k(M)\oplus H_k(N).$$

(For a proof and explanation, see [this Math.Stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/187417).)

Hence, when $n > 1$,

$$H_2(\mathbb{CP}^n\mathbin\#\mathbb{CP}^n)\cong H_2(\mathbb{CP}^n)\oplus H_2(\mathbb{CP}^n)\cong \mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z,$$

so its Betti number is

$$b_2(\mathbb{CP}^n\mathbin\#\mathbb{CP}^n) = \dim H_2(\mathbb{CP}^n\mathbin\#\mathbb{CP}^n) = 2.$$

(When $n = 1$, $\mathbb{CP}^1\cong S^2$, so $\mathbb{CP}^1\mathbin\#\mathbb{CP}^1\cong S^2\mathbin\# S^2\cong S^2$, and $b_2(S^2) = 1$, so to get $b_2 = 2$ one must assume $n > 1$.)